# How to run simple Php API?

Tags: php, api, slim

I used Php Slim Framework for my API. I install the Slim Framework to my web root directory on my server and copy the index.php file I coded.

Index.php:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->contentType('application/json');
$app->get('/users', 'getUsers');
$app->get('/user/:id', 'getUser');
$app->run();

function getConnection() {
$dbhost="localhost";
$dbuser="";
$dbpass="";
$dbname="";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
return $dbh;
}

function getUsers() {
$sql = "select * FROM manga";
try {
$db = getConnection();
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$db = null;
echo json_encode($users);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
}
}
?>
```

I am getting 500 (Internal Server Error).

Edit: I changed "$app = new Slim();" to the "$app = new \Slim\Slim();" then receive the below error.

I am using EasyEngine(Nginx).

[image]

Edit-2:Now 500 Internal gone but another error showing.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.mangayurdu.com/users. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://deneme.mangayurdu.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here is my code that getting JSON data:

```
 .factory('MY', function($http){
  var factory = {};
  var url = 'http://api.mangayurdu.com/users?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
  factory.isimler = $http.get(url);
  return factory;
  })
```

Comment: Have you checked your server (nginx, Apache, ...) logs? What do you see there? Please edit your question to include more details about the error.

Comment: BTW have you also uploaded the `vendor` directory? Reading your question again it seems you only uploaded a single `index.php` file.

Comment: @Gustavo Straube I install the Slim to my server then only copy the index.php i wrote it. Vendor file its already there. I edit my question.

Comment: From your edit, you're hitting the [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Look into CORS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the posted code it looks like Slim can't find a function called `getUser`. `getUsers()` is defined in your code, but no `getUser()` function.

Comment: Yeah I remove the empty function and 500 Internal gone. But still blank page.

Comment: The domain of your executed page and requested domain name for the HTTP request must be the same, for security reasons. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 0):

try putting this in the start of your PHP page

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');?>
```